# jQuery aria-expanded attribute set based on dynamically generated class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the value of aria-expanded based on the existence of a dynamically generated class. The HTML code is quite complex for me to paste here, the closest example would be on this page: https://www.hsbc.am/1/2/am/en/personal. When you go to the `language changer` and clicked it, a new "on" class is added.

[image: 1]

I've managed to change the aria-expanded value if user clicked the language changer. However, it's not really reliable as it's based on click(?) whereby the "on" class can be removed when the user simply "mouseout" from the panel.

Is there any way to do this by simply detecting whether class "on" is exist or not?

Here is my code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click mouseover mouseout', '.on', function() {
        $('#lcaws').attr('aria-expanded', function (i, attr) {
            return attr == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
        });
    });
});
```

And here is part of the HTML code:

```
<div>
  <a id="lcaws" aria-controls="#menuChanger" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="menuChangerLink" >
    <span>English</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.